# Stange issue with image hover in Chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, hover

I have an html/css site that uses an effect to magnify images when you hover over them. It works fine, but when using Chrome, it causes the images to jitter and resize on page load. It doesn't seem to do this in other browsers, and doesn't do it in the Dreamweaver browser test, either. If I remove the effect the page loads fine. Any ideas what could cause this?

Here's a link to the page: http://carissalyn.com/Landing.html

Here is the html for the images:

```
<tr>
<td><a href="" class="imghover"><img src="images/leaf.jpg" alt="portrait" class="border"></a></td>
<td><a href="" class="imghover"><img src="images/DSC_2280-Edit-Edit-Final.jpg"  alt="portrait" class="border"></a></td>
<td><a href="" class="imghover"><img src="images/DSC_2685.jpg" alt="blog" class="border"></a></td>
</tr>
```

and here is the css for the hover:

```
.imghover img{
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 1s; 
-o-transition-duration: 1s; 
}
.imghover img:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); 
-o-transform:scale(1.1); 
}
```

Comment: i dont seem any problem its works fine to me ..

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? Thanks for looking.

Comment: newest version of chrome

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome Version 23.0.1271.91 on Windows 7.

Comment: The issue seems to be the image border:
   img.border{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
}

I took it out temporarily and there were no problems- so if you tried it and the border wasn't there that may be why it worked. If I put it back in the problem comes back.

Comment: Working without problems for me as well. Running Chrome 24.0.1312.25. Have you tested the page without the huge (1.4MB) background? You might want to look at alternative solutions for that, like http://subtlepatterns.com/low-contrast-linen/

Comment: Yeah I had that as a placeholder and wanted to find a smaller one, the one you posted is perfect thanks! I still have the issue thought if I add the padding/border back in to the image though... strange.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Found a fix on [this](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/78) site. It's sort of hackish but seems to work. The key is to add a tiny bit of rotation along with the zoom.

```
.imghover img:hover {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(0.1deg);
}
```